# Can VS Code + rust-analyzer insert inlay hints into the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm writing in rust, but probably the same holds for other languages.

When I type eg `let x = 5`, vscode shows `let x: i32 = 5`, where the `: i32` part is an inlay hint. Is there any way to make vscode insert that hint into the actual code?

Comment: You mean like set the inferred type as an explicit annotation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you hit `Ctrl + .`, then use the arrow keys to select "Insert explicit type `ty`" then hit enter, it will insert it for you.

Comment: that's it!!! do you remember if that's somewhere in the docs??

Comment: @blue_note https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#add_explicit_type