# VS Code + Rust Analyzer: Insert ALL explicit types

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust-analyzer

Going off of [Can VS Code + rust-analyzer insert inlay hints into the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276850/can-vs-code-rust-analyzer-insert-inlay-hints-into-the-code), is there way to insert **all** explicit types into my Rust code?

This is especially useful if I'm pushing it to e.g. GitHub and would like other contributors to be able to view the types without having to look at the code locally on their end.